# How can I make Unity resolve a type to a property of another type?

Tags: .net, unity-container

Imagine I have the following classes:

```
class A
{
    public B B { get; set; }
}

class B
{
}
```

I also have a Unity container with `A` registered as a singleton:

```
container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<A>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

I want to use the container to resolve a `B`:

```
var b = container.Resolve<B>();
```

### Result

A new instance of `B` is in the `b` variable.

### Desired Result

The value of the registered `A`'s `B` property should be returned.

**How can I achieve this?**

### *Additional Information*

In my specific situation, `A` is a Linq to Sql `DataContext`, and `B` is one of the tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an InjectionFactory that returns `A.B` when an instance of B is requested/required:

```cs
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<A>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<B>(new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<A>().B));

var a = container.Resolve<A>();

// A.B is set somewhere
a.B = new B();

var b = container.Resolve<B>();

System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(a.B, b));
```